# How do I calculate a DateTime difference in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
use DateTime ;

my $date = "2010-08-02 09:10:08";

my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' )->set_time_zone('floating');
print $dt->subtract_datetime($date);
```

It's not working; what is the problem?

The error message is:

```
Can't call method "time_zone" without a package or object reference at
/opt/perl/perl5.12/lib/site_perl/5.12.0/x86_64-linux/DateTime.pm line 1338
```

Comment: define your $data var as a datetime :
my $date = DateTime->new(year=>2010, month=>8, day=>2, hour=>9, minute=>10, second=>8);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to convert date strings into DateTime objects first, using a
customized format or one of the many DateTime::Format::* libraries available.
You're using a format commonly used in databases, so I've selected the MySQL
formatter (and then defined a custom duration formatter for the end result,
copied from the examples in
[DateTime::Format::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration)):

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

my $date = "2010-08-02 09:10:08";

my $dt1 = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'floating', formatter => 'DateTime::Format::MySQL');
my $dt2 = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime($date);

my $duration = $dt1 - $dt2;
my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern => '%Y years, %m months, %e days, %H hours, %M minutes, %S seconds'
);
print $format->format_duration($duration);

# prints:
# 0 years, 00 months, 0 days, 00 hours, 421 minutes, 03 seconds
```

Comment: Not sure if anyone will see this, but why does the output come out as 00 hours and 421 minutes.  why not 07 hours 01 minutes?

Comment: @JamesFinnegan because `normalize => 1` wasn't included as an option to DateTime::Format::Duration->new(..).  See https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration.  When that option is added, the output shifts from `0 years, 113 months, 5 days, 00 hours, 804 minutes, 38 seconds` to `9 years, 05 months, 5 days, 13 hours, 24 minutes, 38 seconds`. (I should also note that at the time of my response above, I wasn't yet a maintainer of this module, but now I am.) ;)

Answer (score 6):

`$date` must be a `DateTime` object, not a simple string.  See 
[DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm).  And, you can not simply print the return value of 
`subtract_datetime` because it returns a reference.  You must use
methods, such as `hours`, to extract useful info.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $dt2 = DateTime->new(
                       year   => 2010,
                       month  => 8,
                       day    => 2,
                       hour   => 9,
                       minute => 10,
                       second => 8,
                       time_zone => 'local',
                     );

my $dt1 = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' )->set_time_zone('floating');

my $dur = $dt1->subtract_datetime($dt2);
print 'hours = ', $dur->hours(), "\n";

__END__

hours = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, at first sight, i guess that [`$dt->subtract_datetime(...)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Datetime-Subtraction) will work if you subtract two datetime objects.

ie : your `$date`  should be a datetime