# How can I get the difference of two timestamps using Perl?

Tags: perl

Here i based one problem.. i have two timestamps with same format like (Tue Dec 14 18:23:19 2010 & Tue Dec 14 17:23:19 2010). how can i get the difference of two timestamps in hours.
please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821423/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555101/how-can-i-use-perl-to-do-datetime-comparisons-and-calculate-deltas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388958/how-do-i-calculate-a-datetime-difference-in-perl

Answer (score 10):

```
use Date::Parse;


my $t1 = 'Tue Dec 14 17:23:19 2010';
my $t2 = 'Tue Dec 14 18:23:19 2010';

my $s1 = str2time( $t1 );
my $s2 = str2time( $t2 );

print $s2 - $s1, " seconds\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the DateTime family of classes for pretty much all of my date/time handling.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $dp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
);

# Create two DateTime objects
my $t1 = $dp->parse_datetime('Tue Dec 14 17:23:19 2010');
my $t2 = $dp->parse_datetime('Tue Dec 14 18:23:19 2010');

# The difference is a DateTime::Duration object
my $diff = $t2 - $t1;

print $diff->hours;
```

Comment: but its durations have some gotchas for the unwary.  Your code does not work if the two timestamps have different days.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime.pm) and its *subtract_datetime()* method, which returns a [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime/Duration.pm) object.

```
use Date::Parse;
use DateTime;

my $t1 = 'Tue Dec 14 17:23:19 2010';
my $t2 = 'Tue Dec 14 18:23:19 2010';

my $t1DateTime = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time( $t1 ) );
my $t2DateTime = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time( $t2 ) );

my $diff = $t2DateTime->subtract_datetime( $t1DateTime );

print "Diff in hours: " . $diff->in_units('hours') . "\n";
print "Diff in months: " . $diff->in_units('months') . "\n";
```