# How to get time difference in perl?

Tags: perl

I have two strings which contain time stamps only and look like this - `my $t = "2014-11-28 00:00:00.000";` How do I get the time difference between then in readable time (days, hours, minutes, seconds) and not seconds. I am new and I am facing great difficulty in doing this. Each blog or article is telling me to do different things. Some things can't be done because I don't have the modules. I cannot even install the modules into perl because I have many pearl versions on the computer I am working on. So, cpan > install some::modlue does not help.

Please teach me how to do this. **Please try to use core perl. Otherwise I will have to spend more time in installing perl modules into the right perl**

I made some code to begin with, but its wrong and useless -

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

sub secondsToTime{

    my $inSeconds = shift;
    my $days = int($inSeconds/(24*60*60));
    my $hours = ($inSeconds/(60*60))%24;
    my $mins = ($inSeconds/60)%60;
    my $sec = $inSeconds%60;
    my $time = "$days days, $hours hours, $mins mins, $sec seconds";
    return $time;
}

# EXAMPLE timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year );
my @today = localtime();
print "@today\n";
my $currentTime = timelocal(@today);

#my @t = (0, 00, 13, 28, 11, 2014);
#$currentTime = timelocal(@t);
my @birthday = (0, 00, 12, 28, 11, 2014); 
my $birthTime = timelocal(@birthday);
my $sec = ($currentTime - $birthTime);
my $time = secondsToTime($sec);

print "My age = $time\n";
```

Comment: what timezone are the timestamps in?

Comment: what perl versions do you need to support?

Comment: @ysth - Perl 5.20. Timestamps will be in MST or PST. Would be nice to have something that takes timestamps into account. Thanks.

Comment: @ysth - All these posts are scary. There are either big solutions, solutions that are called wrong by others or solutions that don't use core perl - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460610/how-can-i-get-the-difference-of-two-timestamps-using-perl, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821423/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-perl

Comment: Please give some examples of pairs of date/times, including those that specify time zones. A single example date is worthless, especially one that has zeroes in the time fields. Do you really need to take fractions of a second into account?

Comment: @Borodin - `$l = "2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z";` Assume the time pairs to be PST. I don't need to take the milliseconds into account when showing difference. Only years, month, days, hours, and mins is needed. Thanks.

Comment: The reason why everybody suggests doing it with a module is that doing it right is hard, and it is far easier to run `cpan` (or `cpanp`) and install the relevant modules than it is to write the code to do the job from first principle.  One of the first qualities of a Perl programmer is laziness, in the sense of reusing what others have already done.  The simplest module for you to install is probably [POSIX::strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX%3A%3Astrptime).  The most comprehensive is undoubtedly the (extensive) [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) family of modules.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes, but I am new and I don't know how to install modules into the correct perl. I do all the commands in online tutorials and the wrong perl gets the module. If there is a really easy way to install modules, then I'll do it now. Thanks.

Comment: @smalls: That is the same date and time as you show in the question. Please show *several pairs* of date/times for which you want to calculate the difference. Do they all have zero time fields and no times zone?

Comment: Hmmm...what does that mean?  I simply use the `cpan` or `cpanp` that's installed alongside the Perl I'm using, and everything gets installed in the correct place.  I seldom (functionally never) use the O/S installed Perl — I need versions I can update without risk of breaking the rest of the system, so I have 5.8.9, 5.10.1, 5.12.1, 5.14.2, 5.16.2, 5.18.2 and 5.20.1 installed, and I simply run the `cpanp` in the relevant bin directory (`$HOME/perl/v5.20.1/bin/cpanp`, for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I have perls that were installed by strawberry installer and some other installers. I guess this has something to do with my problem. I had gone into some perl bin directory to run all those install commands. Let me try yours now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - cpanp is not recognized as a command. I'll try CPAN instead. Output is - Writing Makefile for Time::Piece
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  RJBS/Time-Piece-1.29.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 RJBS/Time-Piece-1.29.tar.gz                  : make NO

Comment: `cpanp` is the script for [CPANPLUS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPANPLUS).  You may need to install that first.  I think CPAN still comes as standard.

Comment: If you have multiple installations of Perl then I'm not surprised you're having problems. Remove them all and start again.

Comment: @Borodin - cannot. I need some of them to be there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `CPANPLUS` is hardly essential, but it has been a  core module since version 5.10. `CPAN` has been around since 5.00.

Comment: @smalls: They are useless to you as it stands if you cannot determine which version of perl will be run. What reason do you have for needing multiple versions of Perl?

Comment: @Borodin: and as I understand it, CPANPLUS will become non-core again after 5.20 (presumably 5.22).  Yes, it isn't essential; I prefer it to CPAN, but they're both functional.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It never did much for me. But I find `cpanm` (`App:cpanm`) a big advantage. That has never been in core.

Comment: @Borodin: [App::cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3A%3Acpanminus) installs `cpanm`; I think that was what you meant, wasn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to want to help us understand what it is you need.

This program will print the difference between `2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z` and `2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $start = '2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z';
my $end   = '2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z';

print difference($start, $end);

sub difference {
  my ($beg, $end) = map Time::Piece->strptime(s/\.\d*Z?\z//r, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), @_;
  ($end-$beg)->pretty;
}
```

**output**

```
0 seconds
```

Comment: Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains:

Comment: @smalls: Then you have completely screwed up your Perl installations. `Time::Piece` has been part of core Perl since version 5.010, and if you are running 5.20 and it can't find it then something is seriously amiss. You need to remove *everything* and start from scratch. Take a look at [`App::perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.72/lib/App/perlbrew.pm) if you *really* need to keep multiple versions of Perl.